# How to Cleanly Handle NoSuchKey Errors with AWS Amplify's Storage.get()?

Tags: aws-amplify

I am using AWS Amplify's `Storage` module to retrieve files from an S3 bucket. When trying to get a file that doesn't exist, the function call results in a `NoSuchKey` error, cluttering my console with 404 errors:

```
XHRGET https://my-bucket-url.s3.region.amazonaws.com/path/to/file.png
[HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found xms]

Cannot get file.png from `getFileByName` function: NoSuchKey: The specified key does not exist.
```

Here's my current function for fetching the file:

```
export const getFileByName = async (fileName: ValidFileName, identityId?: string) => {
    try {
        const file = await Storage.get(fileName, {
            level: "protected",
            ...(identityId ? { identityId } : {}), // Conditionally include identityId
            download: true,
            cacheControl: "no-cache",
            validateObjectExistence: true
        });

        return URL.createObjectURL(file["Body"] as Blob);
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(`Cannot get ${fileName} from getFileByName function: `, err)
    }
};
```

My main concern is to gracefully handle the case when the file doesn't exist, without any error being displayed in the console. I want the function to simply return null in case the file is not present.

How can I achieve this cleanly with AWS `Amplify's Storage.get()`? Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!